# PHP - Sessions gets lost after refresh

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have a problem in php. I have implemented a website where it has sign-up and login. During this week login was working but today the sessions have problems.. they get lost after page refresh. I tried to find answers here in stack overflow but i couldn' t. Here is the code

```
<?php @session_start(); ?>
<?php require_once('Connections/connection.php'); ?>
<?php

mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
$query_login2 = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
$login2 = mysql_query($query_login2, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_login2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($login2);
$totalRows_login2 = mysql_num_rows($login2);



$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if (isset($_POST['usernamelog'])) {
    $query_User = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE Email= %s", GetSQLValueString($_POST['usernamelog'], "text"));
    $User = mysql_query($query_User, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_User = mysql_fetch_assoc($User);
    $totalRows_User = mysql_num_rows($User);
    $username = $row_User['Email'];
    $statuss= $row_User['Status'];

    $usernamee = $_POST['usernamelog'];
    $password = $_POST['passwordlog'];
  mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT Status, Email, Password FROM `users` WHERE Email=%s AND Password=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($usernamee, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  //echo $loginFoundUser;
  if ($loginFoundUser) {    
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $usernamee;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;   

  }
}
$colname_User = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
  $_SESSION['MM_Usernamee'] = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
}
/******$_SESSION['MM_Usernamee'] IS LOST AFTER REFRESH********/
    mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
    $query_User = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE Email= %s", GetSQLValueString($_SESSION['MM_Usernamee'], "text"));
    $User = mysql_query($query_User, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_User = mysql_fetch_assoc($User);
    $totalRows_User = mysql_num_rows($User);
    $username = $row_User['Email'];
    $status= $row_User['Status'];

    ?>
```

P.S. Is is working fine on Localhost.

The corrent answer is in the comments of teh answer!!!

Comment: Why @session_start() ?? Must be just session_start().

Comment: I tried this but still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older version of PHP you must before setting session variable use method session_register('[session_name]')

So try:

```
<?php
session_start();

if ( ! isset($_SESSION['session_name'])
{
    session_register('session_name');
    $_SESSION['session_name'] = 'Session value';
}

echo $_SESSION['session_name'];
```

Edit: Before you write

```
<?php session_start()
```

you can't have any text, not even a space. Because then the headers is sent before session can set his own header.
So you must check if start of PHP is first what is loaded in this script. 
Even if you use "include" to load this script, before it can't be any text.

Comment: i am getting this error  Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_register() in /home...on line 93

Comment: and if i use session_start() instead @session_start() i get this error Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent..

Comment: Do you have any idea how is it possible the login to work yesterday but not today???And why is it working on localhost and not on the web ??

Comment: Now I know where is error. I add solution to my answer.

Comment: Some web hosting have bad setting and sending their headers first and than load your script. Try to write them and ask for fix.

Comment: Thnaks bro! that was the problem indeed!